# Tampermonkey-Javascript Icon at root of context sub-menu

Tags: javascript, menu, contextmenu

I'm setting up an extension context menu for a client/server app using Tampermonkey. I want to have a menu item->3xsub menu items.

The menu works and I can get icons on the sub-menu items, but NOT on the main item

I use the code below (not including the full png code for clarity)

```
menu.outerHTML = '<menu id="userscript-context-menu" type="context">\
                    <menu label="My Options\u2026"\
icon="data:image/png;base64,\
iVBORw0KGgoA5ErkJggg==">\
                      <menuitem label="Delete item"\
                                icon="data:application/ico;base64,\
EimHpMQX36bGi+5A/mC6/EOVORK5CYII=">\
                      </menuitem>\
                      <menuitem label="Clear item"\
                                icon="data:application/ico;base64,\
EimHpMQX36bGi+5A/mC6/EOVORK5CYII=">\
                      </menuitem>\
                      <menuitem label="Spread Item"\
                                icon="data:application/ico;base64,\
uOjDAE+O3orkJggg==">\
                      </menuitem>\
                    </menu>\
                  </menu>';


var html = document.documentElement;
html.setAttribute("contextmenu", "userscript-context-menu");

// If browser supports contextmenu
if ("contextMenu" in html && "HTMLMenuItemElement" in window) {
  // Executed on clicking a menuitem
  $("#userscript-context-menu menu").addEventListener("click", my_functions, false);
  html.addEventListener("contextmenu", initMenu, false); // Executed on right clicking
}

//SHOW MENU
//------------------------------------------
function initMenu(e) {
  var node = e.target;
  var title = document.title;

  console.log("better context init", node);

  var menu = $("#userscript-context-menu menu");

//MENU OPTION HANDLER
//------------------------------------------
function my_function(e) {

switch (e.target.label) {
case "Delete item":
        //do something
        break;
case "Clear item":
        //do something else
        break;
case "Spread Item":
        //do something else else
        break;
default:
       alert("shouldn't be here");
       }
}
```

Menu displays and works in terms of functions.

I get icons for the sub-menu items, but NOT for the main menu. Why no icon on the main menu ? What am I missing ?